# C# Regex Match Filenames in dynamic Html Document

Tags: c#

I've this kind of urls in a html document

1. /assets/sdluxdczm3ee4000/
2. /assets/sdluxdczm3ee4000
3. assets/sdluxdczm3ee4000/
4. assets/sdluxdczm3ee4000

I want to match -> **sdluxdczm3ee4000**, to get out all filenames in whole html document.
Is there a way to write a regex to match only this cases?

The closest I've got to solution is:  **\bassets\w*(.+)$** and **(?=assets\b)\w+**

Comment: Not really a `c#` question. More info on the format in the html would be good too. Are the urls plain text in the html or part of a `href` hyperlink, or something else,...?

Comment: They might be part of href, img src, background-image or anything as users have TinyMCE and can put assets anywhere. But I was thinking if it doesn’t end with / it should always end with “ to close html attribute like href or src. I tagged C# because regexe formats can be different for different programming languages.

Comment: But yeah plain text is not considered, it should be part of html attribute that loads asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

`\/?assets\/\w+\/?`